# Работа с URL, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Работаю с Node.js.

У меня задача такая: мне надо из файла index.js взять переменную, впихнуть её в URL при переходе на HTML страницу кодом:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

И потом на той странице использовать эту переменную. Она динамическая и генерируется в JS файле.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и прицепи её к URL как GET параметр

Comment: Если имеете ввиду добавить до index.html параметр, то сайт ищет файл "index.htnl+параметр", которого у меня нету

Comment: Почитайте про передачу GET параметров. Сайт найдёт index.html?var=my_param